# Why do PNG images come out different?

Tags: image, png

I have an image which is separated into 4 pieces, I connect them using 3 different methods.

1. By hand in Microsoft Paint.
2. By hand in paint.net.
3. Programatically using Python's PIL.

Everytime I save the resulting image in PNG format, my expectation that since PNG is lossless the resulting images should be the exact same, however the size is very different (the paint one is almost twice as large as the last one) and when using a program which compares pixel by pixel ignoring metadata, none of the 3 images are exact same. The program I'm using to compare the files is following Python script.

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

def compare_images(fn1, fn2):
    im1 = Image.open(fn1)
    im2 = Image.open(fn2)
    return (list(im1.getdata()) == list(im2.getdata()))
    
print(compare_images(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: Knowing exactly where the differences are and their magnitude would probably help you figure it out.

Comment: My guess is that you are loading an image in JPEG format, and saving "By hand in Microsoft Paint" and loading the JPEG  image, and saving "By hand in paint.net."... If not JPEG, than some other format that is loaded differently. Try the same with BMP input image (load the BMP and save as PNG with Paint, load the BMP and save with paint.net and with PIL...).

Comment: @MarkRansom I did tests, the difference between paint.net and microsoft paint version was that microsoft paint version was in RGBA and had for each pixel 4th value of 255 (alpha channel), all RGB values were the exact same. When it comes to the version using PIL around 5.6% of the pixels had a small difference, this difference is seen already in the tiles of the images before connecting them, for example 3rd pixel from the top left has RGB = (210, 199, 181) in paint.net and microsoft paint, but when reading data using python's PIL it shows RGB = (208, 200, 181).

Comment: So now you know why Microsoft Paint is different, congratulations.  The small difference you found with PIL is exactly what you'd expect from decoding differences on a lossy format like JPEG, suggesting @Rotem is right.  You never told us the source of these images.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't think it was relevant, because I didn't know it was possible, I thought the only data loss occurs when compressing to JPG and that there is only one way to decode resulting JPG, it's new knowledge to me.